# Probability of a 5 digit number having at least one 5 or 3

Tags: probability, statistics

I am studying for a statistics test, I have the answer sheet however it does not show the work. If I do not know the process to get the answer it's of no use.

To clarify, the numbers can begin with 0. The numbers included in the probability may contain either a 5, or a 3 anywhere within them. I've tried doing my best to math it but I keep coming out slightly off. Please help.

Comment: Hint: inclusion-exclusion principle

Comment: You haven't given us the answer—presumably not to prejudice us, but I suspect that really won't be a problem.  Is it $1-(4/5)^5 = 2101/3125$?

Comment: Sorry, the answer is 0.68142. I notice yours comes out slightly less than that. Would removing numbers that start with 0 correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the wording of the problem, it can be solved by determining the probability that the number has *no* $3$ *or* $5$ in it, and then subtracting that from $1$ to get the probability that it has at least one $3$ or $5$ in it.

A number has no $3$ or $5$ in it if and only if it contains numbers selected from $\{0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.  Each digit thus has a $8/10 = 4/5$ probability of qualifying, and since there are five digits, the overall probability of containing no $3$ or $5$ is $(4/5)^5 = 1024/3125$.  Then the probability of having at least one $3$ or $5$ is one minus that, or $2101/3125$.

ETA: If the number must be exactly a five-digit number (i.e., no number less than $10000$), then the result is obtained as $1-(7/9)(4/5)^4 = 3833/5625 = 0.6814\overline{2}$, as fits your teacher's answer.  The $7/9$ comes about because now numbers that have no $3$ or $5$ anywhere must choose, out of the $9$ possible digits ($1$ through $9$ instead of $0$ through $9$), one of the $7$ that aren't $3$ or $5$.

Comment: The answer I've been provided with is 0.68142. I notice yours comes out slightly less than that. Would removing numbers that start with 0 correct that? Is there potentially other factors at work? Or did my teacher math wrong?

Comment: Normally, we don't use "math" as a verb. :-)  Let me look at the revised problem and see if that changes things.

Comment: Added the change.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps enormously. I promise to stop using maths as a verb.

Comment: No biggie, just thought it was a little odd that you used it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Not allowing for numbers beginning with 0:

To find all numbers without any 3 or 5s would be 7/9 choices for the first digit (as it can't be zero) and 8/10 = 4/5 for the remaining for for $7/9*( 4/5)^4$

So the probability of at least 1 3 or 5 is $(1 - 7/9*(4/5)^4)) = 0.68142...$

So apparently, yes, to be a 5 digit number is can not start with 0.